# Remove unused docker images by java code

Tags: java, docker

I want to remove the unused docker images using java code. There is **DockerClient** to remove docker image by image id. But I need to remove all unused docker images on one line code. In command line, we can achieve it by,

***docker image prune -a***. But I need to perform this action by java code. Still, i can't find any dependency to perform that. can you help me to solve this?

Comment: What about calling any system command from Java by using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)` ?

Comment: Have you tried doing something like this: ` docker.removeImage("", false, true);`?

Comment: its not working **docker.removeImage("", false, true);**

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned Docker remote api is the way to go, and better and safer way than using the system calls imo.
To be able to call the Docker rest apis, you need to start a HTTP server while starting up docker, it typically listens at `localhost:2375`, but that is configurable in docker.sock, or if you are using mac, you can use socat to allow docker to listen on some ip and port.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Java developer. I do think, however, that your best bet is to use the [Docker Remote API](https://docs.docker.com/develop/sdk/). You can use the HTTP version. That will allow you to use the HTTP library of your choice to run Docker commands.